# Django pass parameter when using urls include

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

In `urls.py` I dynamically create objects and want to create urls for each of them. I can iterate over them and include another `urls` file into my main `urls.py` like this:

```
urlpatterns = [path(object.url, include('bar.urls')) for object in objects]
```

However, in my application I want to pass the variable `object` to `bar.urls` that can be passed to the views afterward. I wonder if I can do something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [path('foo', include('bar.urls', my_var=object)) for object in objects]
```

and in `bar`:

```
# bar.urls (got my_var somehow)
urlpatterns = [path('foo', views.foo, object=my_var)]

# bar.views
def foo(request, object)
    # use object
```

Comment: You should always start by [reading the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.include).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who (like me) have problems reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-include) properly. You can do the following:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [path(object.url, include('bar.urls'), {'var': object}) for object in objects]
```

This will automatically pass `object` to every view as its last parameter:

```
# bar.urls
urlpatterns = [path('foo', views.foo)]

# bar.views
def foo(request, var)
    # use object
```